# How to open a new window in latest Xcode 12 beta?

Tags: xcode12

How can I open a new window editor in latest Xcode 12 beta?

[image]

**Edit: Dragging from the top navigation bar doesn't work, too.**

Edit: This has beened fixed in Version 12.0 beta 4 (12A8179i)

Answer (score 3):

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (or using File > New > Window) will open the current file in a new window. This is the best solution I have found.

Comment: Oh my god, one of the main things I liked about xcode was the option to quickly open file in new editor and its gone now.

Comment: Actually it opens the entire current tab in a new window (not just current file)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable 'open in New Window' by setting navigation in Xcode - Preferences.

[image]

By setting Navigation style and optional navigation, you can see 'Open in New Window' when right-click.

[image]